# Train simple RNN from my own dataset in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, training-data

edited after @Nerveless_child answer
I have a file with words-bitstrings as key and True/False for value which represents if word is in my dictionary.

> 010000101010000, False

> 10100010110010001011, True

The words represents kind of pattern and I want to train rnn network that can identify if word is in the language or not (simple binary classifier).

my Dataset:

```
class myDataset(T.utils.data.Dataset):
# WORD  T/f
# 010000101010000  FALSE

    tmp_x = np.loadtxt(src_file, max_rows=m_rows,
                       usecols=[0], delimiter=",", skiprows=0, 
    dtype=np.int64)

    tmp_y = np.genfromtxt(src_file, max_rows=m_rows,
                       usecols=[1], delimiter=",", dtype=bool)

    tmp_y = tmp_y.reshape(-1, 1)  # 2-D required

    self.x_data = T.from_numpy(tmp_x).to(device)


def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self.x_data[index], self.y_data[index]

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.x_data)
```

and when I'm trying to train the network

```
    net.train()  # set mode
for epoch in range(0, max_epochs):
    T.manual_seed(1 + epoch)  # recovery reproducibility
    epoch_loss = 0  # for one full epoch

    for (batch_idx, batch) in enumerate(train_ldr):
        (X, Y) = batch  # (predictors, targets)
        optimizer.zero_grad()  # prepare gradients
        oupt = net(X)  # predicted prices
        loss_val = loss_func(oupt, Y)  # avg per item in batch
        epoch_loss += loss_val.item()  # accumulate avgs
        loss_val.backward()  # compute gradients
        optimizer.step()  # update wts
```

I get the error

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: Why did you comment this lines `# self.x_data = T.tensor(tmp_x).to(device)
    # self.y_data = T.tensor(tmp_y).to(device)`?

Comment: The error as to do with your data, `self.x_data` and `self.y_data`, being **string** instead of integers and booleans like you expected.

Comment: Hi since otherwise I get the error:
`TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.str_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.`

Comment: Ha ha! I will write my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```py
def __init__(self, src_file, m_rows=None):
    tmp_x = np.loadtxt(src_file, max_rows=m_rows,
                        usecols=[0], delimiter=",", skiprows=0, dtype=int)
    tmp_y = np.loadtxt(src_file, max_rows=m_rows,
                        usecols=[1], delimiter=",", skiprows=0, dtype=bool)

    tmp_y = tmp_y.reshape(-1, 1)  # 2-D required

    self.x_data = T.from_numpy(tmp_x).to(device)
    self.y_data = T.from_numpy(tmp_y).to(device)
```

I would also suggest you use [np.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) as you data file gets more complicated.

Comment: got `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

Comment: Try changing `int` to `np.int64` on this line `tmp_x = np.loadtxt(src_file, max_rows=m_rows,
                        usecols=[0], delimiter=",", skiprows=0, dtype=int)`

Comment: didn't work,
worked after change to
`tmp_x = np.genfromtxt(src_file, max_rows=m_rows,
                           usecols=[0], delimiter=",", dtype='str')`
and
`tmp_y = np.genfromtxt(src_file, max_rows=m_rows,
                           usecols=[1], delimiter=",", dtype=bool)`

Comment: you right...
still problem when type is str..
`TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.str_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.`

Comment: That's because there is no tensor type that handles strings, so you would have to represent your data in other ways.

Comment: so how can we load trainset of long bitstrings?

Comment: That would have to be a different question with the relevant information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228813/discussion-between-user14942713-and-nerveless-child).